# python import module does not return to prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a module that behaves differently when executed from command line or is imported as a module, e.g.:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Aloha Main")
else:
    print("Aloha Module")
```

Though, when i import this module in python3 interactive session, I don't get the prompt return, I have to press an extra "Enter" to get the prompt back. The same when calling the the functions in this module. The problem disappears when I comment out the "print" statement after "else:". Is it possible to get the prompt back even wiht "print" in place?

UPDATE: Here is a test.py that demonstrates this behaviour

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Aloha Main")
else:
    print("Aloha Module")
```

and I get:

```
% python3
Python 3.6.0 (default, Dec 23 2016, 12:51:31) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import test
>>> Aloha Module

>>>
```

I had to press enter to get back to the prompt after "Aloha Module". This is running Python 3.6 on OSX. No problems on Python 2.7 on the same system.

UPDATE 2: This is specifically an issue in OSX 10.11.6, I tested this on my Linux box and I did get the prompt back under python 3.6. I use the OSX built-in terminal.

Comment: Do you get that behavior with the posted code? If not, is it possible your code is attempting to read from stdin?

Comment: I suspect you got the prompt, but it got intermingled or overwritten by your print.

Comment: Having just tested that exact code (saved in a module named `testprint.py`) in an interactive session (Python 3.5, Ubuntu), the `import testprint` printed just fine, and I got a prompt as normal, no need to hit Enter again. You're not giving enough information to reproduce...

Comment: Is this in IDLE or something?

Comment: Either it's a change in `import` behaviour in 3.6 (unlikely) or you're working in a terminal setup that delays output. Maybe it's a change in stream buffering in 3.6.

Comment: The interesting thing is that you have the prompt printed on the same line as the text:  `>>> Aloha Module`.  So it looks like it's just something in the way the terminal is mixing the output from `print` and the output from the REPL.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: If it was changed in 3.6, it changed back quickly. I have a (month old) build of 3.7.0a0, and it doesn't have this behavior in Ubuntu on `bash`.